# Edit text of Wordpress "Register" button

Tags: users, user-registration

On the default WP registration page I want to edit the text of the blue button from "Register" to "Accept and Register".
I want to do this without using a plugin, if possible.
[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like the out-of-the-box registration page. You may need to see what plugin is setting up all the preamble to be able to filter the register button text. And if you're against using plugins, you'll need to create a child theme to run your filter to change the text.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am using the "Force Login" plugin, but that uses the default WP registration page.
It doesn't look like the normal registration page because I've already edited the text to add the disclaimer with some extra code I had googled and added to my functions.php.
This is my own theme, and I do want to run a filter, but I don't know how to do it for the button text. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a particular string, you can use the `gettext` hook:

```
/*
 * Using priority 20 to override the default 10.
 * If another theme or plugin has a higher number,
 * you might need to raise this.
 */
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_change_strings', 20 );

function wpse_change_strings( $translated_text ) {
    // If this is the specific string to change, update it.
    if ( 'Register' === $translated_text ) {
        // Change this to your desired string.
        $translated_text = 'Updated Call to Action';
    }

    // Always return the text, whether we changed it or not.
    return $translated_text;
}
```

The above is case-sensitive. You could use `strtolower($translated_text)` to compare if you'd like to change the text regardless of capitalization.

Comment: That works beautifully, thank you - sorry I didn't thank you before.

For other beginners:
If you need to add more filters, copy the code into your functions.php again, but replace each instance of the text "wpse_change_strings" to your own new function name.

Comment: It will help future readers if you mark this answer as accepted. :)